# how to get data from graphql server using react and react-apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

After about 6-8 hours trying, I'm resorting to help.
**All I want is to query my graphql server and the response data to be entered into my react component as props (See ParameterBox.js).** Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

**For Reference: INDEX.JS FILE (Likely correct)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    ApolloClient,
    createNetworkInterface,
    ApolloProvider,
} from 'react-apollo';
import App from './App';


const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql'
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface: networkInterface
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**For Reference: APP.JS FILE (I think it's correct)**

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ParameterBox from './ParameterBox';

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ParameterBox />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

**PARAMETERBOX.JS FILE (Here is where the issue is, somewhere...)**

```
//ParameterBox.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { gql, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import ParameterList from './ParameterList';

class ParameterBox extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
        this.loadParamsFromServer = this.loadParamsFromServer.bind(this);
    }
    //*** Old Method ***/
    // I still set my data using the old methods of API urls. I want to switch to GraphQL
    loadParamsFromServer(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/params')
            .then (res => {
                this.setState({ data: res.data });
            })
    }
    //**** end old method ****/
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadParamsFromServer();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div >
                <h2> Parameters: </h2>
                <p> HOW DO I GET IT HERE? {this.props.AllParamsQuery } </p>
                <ParameterList
                    data={ this.state.data }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const AllParams = gql`
    query AllParamsQuery {
        params {
            id,
            param,
            input
        }
    }`;

export default graphql(AllParams, {name: 'AllParamsQuery'})(ParameterBox);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find it helpful to review the Apollo documentation for basic queries [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html).

When you wrap your component with the `graphql` HOC, it will send your query to the server and then make the result available to your component as `this.props.data`. So, the result for your particular query would be found at `this.props.data.params` (the operation name, `AllParamsQuery` is not referenced inside the returned data).

The other thing to bear in mind is that the GraphQL is asynchronous, so while `props.data` will always be available, initially it will be empty. Your render logic will need to account for that fact by verifying that `this.props.data.params` is truthy before tyring to render it. You can also check whether the query is [still in flight or has completed](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data-loading).

**Edit**: because you define a name property (`AllParamsQuery`) inside the config object you pass to `graphql()`, your query results will be available as that prop instead of `data` -- i.e. 'this.props.AllParamsQuery.params`.

Comment: thank you! I kept defining it as states, but it wasn't under state. However `this.props.data.params` didn't work, `this.props.AllParamsQuery.params` worked. I will need to set the props data to the query if I wan't to use `data` instead of `AllParamsQuery`

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that you were passing a name to config. I updated the answer to reflect that :)